# Perl qx execution order in array initialization

Tags: arrays, perl, system, backticks

Assuming I have the following:

```
my @net = (`echo "HELLO" > file`,
           `less file`);
```

is it guaranteed that the order of execution is from 0..N (the first element in the array is executed first, then the second,etc..)?

I've tested this, and this is what really happens, but can I count on that?

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Each of the comma-separated items in your brackets `()` on the right-hand side are [*terms*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Terms-and-List-Operators-%28Leftward%29).  These have the highest precedence in Perl, and evaluate left-to-right.  Backticks are [quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: cool! thanks for the reference to the perldoc, couldn't find it earlier.